# Create action is not working (for model with has many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am build a Rails app which does the following: a user can create a new project and, inside each Project, it can create different Papers.

I am starting building it from the outer layer (meaning, I first want to be able to create, update, delete a Project before starting to code the Papers part).

I have the following problem: I coded the new and create action for the `project_controllers` but the new entity is not saved. (It is not displayed in `index.html.erb` and the `_form.html.erb` keeps rendering, which means it is not saving)

I think the issue is that a Project `has_many` Papers and since I have not coded yet the Paper part, it creates issues. BUT I am not sure if this is the right answer.

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :papers, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**project_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.save
    if @project.save
      redirect_to projects_path()
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @project.update(project_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form', project: @project %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title, "Title of the Project"%>
        <%= f.text_field :title, as: :string, class: 'form-control'%>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body, "Description of the Project"%>
        <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 20, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>


      <%= f.submit "Confirm",  class:"btn btn-secondary btn-lg" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The quick and easy way to tell if the issue is the has_many is to just remove the line and see if it saves. Try it out and post the results please.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it seems indeed that the problem

Comment: I would just remove that line until you’ve coded the Paper part then.